# Wifi connection gets slow when changing back from router 2 to router 1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, wifi-configuration

I have two routers in the same network with different SSIDs and when I change a wireless device from Router 1 to Router 2, the connection is okay, but when I change its WiFi back to Router 1 from Router 2, the connection becomes very slow:

- Router 1: `192.168.0.1` [MTU: `1492`]
- Router 2: `192.168.0.2` [MTU: `1492`] is connected via ethernet to the LAN port

  - DHCP Server is off
  - Same result occurs whether DNS server is set to Auto or manually set

Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: What's the reason to change from 1st to 2nd and back? Where are you physically in relation to both when changing?

Comment: What is the need to change routers back and forth. Run TCP/IP reset each time. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  netsh int ip  reset and see if that helps

Comment: It's not the routers, it's the wifi connection. The reason to change it's because I get far from one router and the laptop connects to the nearest one

Comment: I've already reserved a specific IP for the MAC of the laptop in both routers but the issue continues

Comment: @CAS Are the WiFi radio channels on the routers set to `Auto` or a physical channel? The most likely scenario is when switching back to Router 1's WiFi network, the device is getting a poor channel assigned to it's connection. If the channels are set to `Auto`, change to: 2.4GHz: `1`, `6`, or `11` | 5GHz: Highest DFS channel available, else highest available channel (`157` works well in the US), _unless_ using a 160MHz bandwidth, in which case there are only two DFS channels available. `Auto` should never be used.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ You may have a specific reason for wanting each router with its separate WiFi, however if not, you may benefit from configuring one as a WiFi access point, which extends the WiFi network range of the main router.

Comment: The second it's configured as access point, even though the router does not have that option the DHCP server option is OFF on the second one.
They are configured to use different channels.

Answer (score 0):

The router was send to warranty. There was an issue and it was replaced by a new one. Thank you for your comments